# How do I assign up addresses to my network devices by order of importance?

Tags: networking

I am replacing some physical servers in my network and replacing them with Hyper-V machines.  Which of course ips are already assigned to the current network.  I just want to know the order of importance for assigning the up addresses.  For example. My domain controller (which I believe is the most important) will be 192.168 .1.1. After the DC what is the order of the next devices?

I will have two hyperv machines, running windows and Linux vms.  I will have two file servers (physical), a backup server (physical), EPO server (vm), etc.

Again, I am just looking for something that will tell me how to open devices in order of importance.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Order means nothing, it is just a convention and makes it easier to remember.  Gateways/routers are typically at .1 (almost everything) or .254 (I've seen it twice), anything else is up to local policy/documentation.

What I would do is use MAC address based "static" IP leases in your DHCP server, and add appropriate DNS entries using a real domain name that you own but that isn't your website, email, etc. domain.  For example, I work for a university and our internal name isn't school.edu but rather generic looking four letter domain in the `.us` name space, so our internal hostnames look like lp32.its.abcd.us (**l**inux **p**hysical number 32) or wv17.vhost03.its.abcd.us for "windows virtualized on virtual host box 03".

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you ivanivan.  I was thinking the same thing but got confused as I was doing some research.  I guess sometimes too much research can be a bad thing also.  Again, thank you and I do appreciate the quick response.